# Java JDK 18 is not installing windows 10

Tags: java

I'm trying to install JDK-18 on my windows machine, but the installer gets closed immediately. Previously I had installed Java 8(Update 311) for some reason and its installation file is missing now. What should I do to install JDK-18 freshly and remove Java 8 entirely?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove Java 8 completely because its installation seems to be broken. Check https://java.com/ for help, it contains an uninstall tool.

Take **Open** JDK 18 from https://jdk.java.net/18/. It is available as zip file (https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk18.0.1.1/65ae32619e2f40f3a9af3af1851d6e19/2/GPL/openjdk-18.0.1.1_windows-x64_bin.zip).

Unzip it into a folder and use it from command line or an IDE.

P.S.: It is preferable to take version 17 as it is a longterm supported version.

Comment: as you can @franck see the update 311 installation file is missing, so it is not removing (tried many times).

Comment: https://java.com/en/uninstall/ "Keeping out-of-date versions of Java on your system may present a serious security risk. To help you remove out-of-date Java installations, we have created a Java Uninstall Tool (https://java.com/en/download/uninstalltool.jsp).

If you are unable to use the tool, please see the instruction page which provides step by step details on how to remove Java installation(s) (https://java.com/en/uninstall/uninstall_instructions.html#Windows%2010)"

Comment: They offer even personalized help: "Uninstall Help Request Form" (https://java.com/en/uninstall/uninstall_instructions.html#:~:text=Uninstall%20Help%20Request%20Form) "This page is for requesting help on uninstalling out-of-date versions of Java from Windows/MAC Machines. If you are experiencing other issues and you require help please see the Java.com Support page. Please provide your email address for us to contact you with further steps to remove Java from your system or, if necessary, to ask questions in order to better understand the issue you are facing."

Comment: Yes, I just filled out the form for uninstallation.
I truly appreciate your help, Thank You.

Comment: Besides this issue you can download the **Open** JDK as zip file, https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk18.0.1.1/65ae32619e2f40f3a9af3af1851d6e19/2/GPL/openjdk-18.0.1.1_windows-x64_bin.zip, unzip it into a folder and use it from command line or an IDE.

Comment: Why would the presence of Java 8 interfere with the installation of Java 18?

Comment: @BasilBourque The magic of an installer which does system-deep integration and encounters a broken (he mentioned missing files) installation whose installed components don't behave as expected? Of course, it could also be a general problem on his system. I think of *Please re-install Windows on your system and do all system updates. Then install Java.* as a last resort method. Therefore, better check first with a non-installer JDK. Additionally, the people from Oracle might have an idea or two about typical problems regarding their particular installers.

Comment: @Franck thank you so much, **Open JDK** did my job.

Answer (score 1):

You have not explained what installer you used, nor where you obtained it. So we cannot diagnose your problem.

Reviewing your logs may provide details about the failure of your installer.

I suggest you get a fresh installer from any of the several vendors. These include, in no particular order: Amazon, Adoptium, SAP, Azul Systems, Microsoft, Red Hat/IBM, Oracle, BellSoft, Pivotal, and more. Be sure to read their licensing terms; some are free-of-cost, some are not.

- Be sure to get an installer appropriate to your host OS, Microsoft Windows apparently in your case. Be sure the version of your host OS is supported.
- Be sure to use an installer appropriate to the CPU architecture of your host computer. For Windows that will be either 32-bit or 64-bit generations of either [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) or [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family).

So you have three factors to get right in choosing to download a JDK: 
*Host OS > x86 or ARM > 32-bit or 64-bit*.

I am guessing you got one of those factors wrong in your previous attempt.

As for the [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72358415/642706) that suggests deleting Java 8, I cannot imagine how that would be of help to you. You should be able to have multiple versions of Java installed on the same machine. Having multiple versions is very common among developers and testers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to switch the general `JDK version` between projects for example, you can use tools like [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/install) to manage different versions of your jdk.

Comment: *sdkman* has room to grow on Windows: 
*Please be aware that as SDKMAN is written in bash, it requires a bash environment to be present. SDKMAN can not be installed natively on Windows and requires WSL, Cygwin or MSYS+MinGW.*